# Можно ли как-то обозначить разницу между терминами?

Tags: значение-слов, выбор-слов

Есть множество терминов для *людей связанных с магией*, можно ли как-то их различать и есть ли между ними отличия и разница?

**Маг, Чародей, Волшебник, Колдун, Чернокнижник, Кудесник, Волхв, Некромант**?

Answer (score 3):

Все понятия связаны с колдовством,т.е. со сверхъестественными силами.

Чародей, кудесник и волшебник, по-моему,полные синонимы, выдуманные персонажи сказок, способные совершать чудеса, т.е. что-то сверхъестественное,они в основном добрые. Только чародей - устаревшее.

Колдун тоже есть в сказках, но он там обязательно злой.Колдунья, ведьма.Но колдун перешёл и в жизнь.У древних племён обязательно был колдун - защитник племени.

Чернокнижник-колдун,взаимодействующий с «нечистой силой».

Волхв - чародей, колдун у древних славян.Иногда в балладах их называли и кудесниками.

Маг и колдун сейчас - близкие понятия.  Магия- совокупность действий и слов, обладающих чудодейственными свойствами и способных подчинить сверхъестественные силы. Колдовство – магические приёмы, имеющие целью воздействовать  на людей и силы природы, исцелять или навредить человеку.
Мне кажется, маг на порядок выше,он может сам создать что-то, а колдун пользуется приёмами, доставшимися ему по наследству, он только исполняет ритуал (как ремесленник в отличие от мастера, художника)

Некромант- это тот кто работает с энергией смерти и сознаниями, не всегда мёртвыми,с духами, он может оживлять мёртвых, если  шаман работает и  с растениями, и с животными силами, тотемами, то некромант только с мёртвецами.

**Если подойти с точки зрения этимологии:**

маг Заимств. в XVIII в. из нем. яз., где Magus < лат. magus, восходящего к греч. magos «жрец» (индийско-персидской касты) — из др.-перс. Maguš, названия племени, из представителей которого выходили жрецы. Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004

Ещё одна версия:http://lib3.podelise.ru/docs/3248/index-69385-1.html?page=5
Маг - человек, изменяющий окружающий мир, посредством магических приемов и ритуалов. Этимология слова восходит к лат. magus - волшебство, магия. Дословно это означает «скрытое движение». Поэтому иллюзионистов также часто называют магами.

Есть ещё: впервые слово магия упоминается в Упанишадах( трактаты, относящиеся к Ведам). Происходит, там от индо-славянского или протосанскритского корня "Маха". До сих пор существует в Форме таких слов, как "Махарадж", "Махатма" и т.д. Обозначает нечто гигантское, грандиозное, возвышенное и сильное. Первоначально применялось в словах, где это величие отождествлялось с внутренней и духовной силой.Далее примерно в 7-6 веках до нашей эры перекочевывает в Иран. Это хорошо видно по всей Иранской мифологии, где религиозные термины, немного искаженные Индийские. Имена многих божеств, также имеют индийское происхождение. Шло время, в 6-5 веке* до нашей эры, в восточном Иране завелся Заратушра, который основал Маздеизм. По Гермодору Сиракузскому, первый из магов - Заратуштра
http://oldwizard.ru/index.php?/topic/17509-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3/

Чары-общеславянское от праславянского чар - "средство", "помощь", индоевр.корень *ker-резать-делать-колдовать "к" изменился в "ч".Чародей - тот, кто околдовывает.

В древнерусском слово "чудо" звучало как "кудо"; родительный падеж у него был "кудесе" (ср. "небо" - "небесе").Очевидно, "кудесник" - старая форма слова "чудесник", "чудотворец".

Слово «волшебник» происходит от прилагательного «волшебный», а оно, в свою очередь, из праславянского «*vъlšьba» - «колдовство».

Волхвы - каста магов в кочующих племенах на древних просторах Европы. Этимология слова восходит к фин. velho - «волшебник», другие  сопоставляют это с именем бога «Волоха». Дословно - «управитель источником жизни и смерти». В некоторых других языках близкие по звучанию слова обозначают волшебников, гадалок.

Есть и такое объяснение:

В первобытные охотничьи времена медведь стал олицетворением «духа леса», хозяином леса, от него зависела удача или неудача охотника. Со временем появияся «дух убитого зверя», «дух охотничей добычи». Туша побеждённого зверя была единственным богатством охотника-язычника. А имя богу богатства, «духу охотничей добычи» дали Волос.  Медведь – космат или, как говорили в старину, «волохат». А  «волохатый» и «волосатый» - равные по значению слова, синонимы.
 Волохатый – волосатый – Волос (или Велес). Отсюда  «волхв» – служитель культа Волоса-Велеса. Этот служитель для совершения какого-то ритуала возможно надевал на себя медвежью шкуру. Волхвы, заклиная и ведя волшбу, делали ритуальные пасы и движения – волховали. Результаты волхования нередко были неожиданными, чудодейственными, волшебными.

Колдун.Общепринятой этимологии не существует, по Крылову,возможно, родственно литовскому kaiba – "язык", ведь первоначальное значение слова колдун – "заклинатель, заговариватель".

caldina (лат.): cal(i)dus - «теплые внутренности только что убитого животного», наводит на мысль, что первоначально колдунами называли тех, кто предсказывал события по потрохам животных. Такие ритуалы были, например, у древних греков.

Есть ещё толкователь латинского:КОЛДУН – это жрец, выполняющий сомнительные ритуалы.– kol – торжественный ритуал; dow – раздвоенность, сомнение – это КОЛДОВАТЬ; слово КОЛДУН образовалось из таких трёх элементов: kol – торжественный ритуал; dow – раздвоенность, сомнение, wen – жрец.

некромант - от некроз-греч.мёртвый

чернокнижник - само за себя говорит: тот, кто колдует по чёрным книгам, с помощью тёмных сил.

Comment: Мало очень информации.. Откуда каждое слово зародилось? Какие корни у каждого понятия?

Comment: Ну, это Гогл вам в помощь, посмотрите в Викисловаре каждое. Я на Ваш вопрос ответила, а научное исследование по каждому - это уж сами.

Comment: Вы правда считаете, что я не пытался это сделать уже? Я уже на английском форуме задавал и увы мало кто что-то знает. На форумах РПГ тоже мало кто знает. Уже решил здесь задать!